# AWS Lambda: Java SnapStart allocated array not present

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I want to preallocate a byte array in SnapStart's `beforeCheckpoint()` function, but for some reason trying to access it is giving Null pointer exceptions. Example:

```java
public class Handler implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent>, Resource{
    byte[] data;
    @Override
    public void beforeCheckpoint(org.crac.Context<? extends Resource> context) throws Exception {
        this.data = new byte[4096]; // 100 MB
        new Random().nextBytes(this.data);
    }

@Override
    public void afterRestore(org.crac.Context<? extends Resource> context) {

    }

    @Override
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event, Context context)
    {
    
     for (int i=0; i<4096; i++) {
         System.out.print(this.data[0]);
     }
     ...
```

However, I encounter Null pointer exception when trying to do this, suggesting that this.data is null despite having allocated it in beforeCheckpoint(). How can I fix this so that the allocation is done before the checkpoint and I can access the data after loading the snapshot?

Comment: Are you registering the handler with the global context? Also, where is `data` defined? Your class only appears to define `pageData`. If this isn't the actual code for your Lambda, please post the actual code (or a minimum replicable version).

Comment: @kdgregory, sorry, it's supposed to be data, I've modified it. Do I need to register the handler or just data with global context?

Comment: Yeah, if you look at the documentation, you'll see that the handler must be registered in its constructor. Personally, I've never used those hooks (and don't have much use for SnapStart period).